# Python Lists - How this connection is made?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm reading about algorithms in Python but I'm also new in Python.

I just need to understand how this is made:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = range(8)
N = [
[b, c, d, e, f], # a
[c, e], # b
[d], # c
[e], # d
[f], # e
[c, g, h], # f
[f, h], # g
[f, g] # h
]
print(N[a])

--> Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How can Python knows that the N[a] correspond to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line sets `a=0`, `b=1`, `c=2` etc. The next lines set `N` to a list of lists. The first item in this list is `[b, c, d, e, f]`, which is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` because that's what the values for b, c, d, e and f are.

On the last line you're accessing `N[a]`, which is `N[0]` because `a` is 0. And since `N[0]` means "the first element in `N`" and that's `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, that's what you get.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in the first line the `range(8)`, which is a list with numbers from 0 to 7, is unpacked to 8 names (vars). The `a` name has the value 0 then. So, `N[a]` is actually `N[0]` is actually `[b, c, d, e, f]` is actually `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two hints for you:

1. Figure out what values get assigned to variables `a` through `h`.
2. Substitute the corresponding values instead of the variable names in the code to see whether it makes things clearer for you.

Answer (score 1):

`range(8)` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

This way, the value of `a` is `0` and `b, c, d, e, f` will take the values of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, respectively.

When you access the item of the list `N` under the index `a`, seeing as `a` has a value of `0`, you get the first item of the list, namely `[b, c, d, e, f]`. Seeing as `b, c, d, e, f` are `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, you get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` back.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with arrays? An array is a collection of elements that you can access by using an index. For instance: the array x that contains elements 'u', 'v', 'w':

```
   x = ['u', 'v', 'w']
```

Now, you can access elements in this collection by using the index, or the place of an element in an array, (the count starts from zero here): x[0] is the element 'u', x[1] is 'v', and so on.

The N in your example is such an array. And because you defined

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = range(8)
```

a will be 0 (read the definition of the Python range() function if you're unsure what it does), b will be 1, c is 2, d is 3, e is 4 and f is 5.

Hence, N[a]=N[0], or the first element in the array N, which is [b, c, d, e, f].
And as we've seen above, [b, c, d, e, f] will evaluate to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

I hope this helps, sorry if you already knew some of these aspects.